# RedirectToAction not changing URL or navigating to Index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried using a `RedirectToAction` after I have done a post to the controller and saved but the URL does not change and the redirect does not seem to work. I need to add that the redirect does enter the controller action method when I debug. It does not change the URL or navigate to the `Index` view.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View("Index", new TrainingViewModel());
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
    // save the details and return to list
    return RedirectToAction("Index");    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

jQuery calls:

```
this.SynchValuesToReadOnly = function() {
    window.location = $('#siteRoot').attr('href') + 'Sites/';           
};

this.OnSiteEdit = function() {
    // post back to the server and update the assessment details    
    var options = {
        target: '',
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Site/Edit',
        beforeSubmit: othis.validate,
        success: othis.SynchValuesToReadOnly
    };

    $('#uxSiteForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
};
```

Comment: The code you show is correct. My wild guess is that you're not doing a standard POST (e.g., redirects don't work with an AJAX post). Can you show more code?

Comment: aaaaahhh....did not know that. Yes you are right. It is indeed coming from an ajax post in jquery and that means I should redirect from there if successful. No problems. Put your comment up as an 'answer' and I'll mark when I prove it works if you like
thanks

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The code you show is correct. My wild guess is that you're not doing a standard POST (e.g., redirects don't work with an AJAX post).

The browser will ignore a redirect response to an AJAX POST. It's up to you to redirect in script if you need to redirect when an AJAX call returns a redirect response.

Comment: Good answer. Can you explain why for us?

Comment: When you do an async `POST`, you must manually redirect (in JS) if you get a redirect response. Browsers don't do it automatically. That's all there is to say about this. Browsers assume the script is in charge in this case.

Comment: just complementing and giving some guidance for n00bs like me. In the ajax.beginform instruction, include something like this new AjaxOptions{ OnSuccess="window.location.href = 'ControllerName/Action'" } and voilá

Comment: @Craig Stuntz
Actually Chrome and FF are automatically redirecting pretty well.
IE (version 11 in my case) doesn't ...
but I think at time of the post none did.

Comment: Thanks @Craig. I was stuck with this issue working with .NET 8 and MVC w/ Razor views. I was making a POST request from an external js file(with jQuery) and was wondering why the user is not navigated to the new url. Made changes to make the request from the razor view directly to the controller action w/o going through js file solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add "return false;" to end of your onclick javascript event. For example:

Razor Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID) 
    @Html.ActionLink("Save", "SaveAction", "MainController", null, new { @class = "saveButton", onclick = "return false;" })
}
```

JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.saveButton').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
        });
    });
```

C#

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveAction(SaveViewModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I always forget that "return" is required. Guess I'm so used to the old Response.Redirect that never required a "return".

Answer (score 6):

Try as below:

return in your action:

`return Json(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));`

and in your ajax:

`window.location.href`

Answer (score 6):

I just came across this issue and nothing was working for me. It turned out the controller I was redirecting to required Authorization - the `[Authorize]` attribute was preventing any redirection.

```
[Authorize]//comment this out
public class HomeController : Controller {...}
```

Down the road or in larger projects this may not be a desired fix, but if you're only looking for a simple redirection or starting out, this may be a solution for you.

Comment: Now I understand why I kept getting directed to Login when I attempted a redirect, duh.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I decided to write this comment as a new answer because I think it needs more description and may someone can't see it in comments if has my problem. So I Apologize if you think this is not an answer and must be written in the comment section.

In some cases, I used RedirectToAction to send the user to another action if input values are incorrect or insufficient and avoid continuing the current process as below:

```
if (inputValues == null)
{
  RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

That keeps not working and continues the current process to take unhandled error. I search and read some articles but I can't find a solution. Calling of RedirectToAction is not from Ajax code and routing is so simple without any parameters even. So why is not working? Finally, I found the simple mistake I did: Forgot to put **"return"** keyword before RedirectToAction. I changed the code as below:

```
if (inputValues == null)
{
  return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

And that is worked. Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

Check with firebug. Post might be returning a server error.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late.... but I had the same problem in MVC5. I had 2 actions with the same name, which is common enough. I wasn't getting any errors that I could capture in Application_Error or OnException in the controller. I tried adding in the action, controller, area in the RedirectToAction route variable to no avail. I ended up renaming the POST action to EditPost and everything works now for me. Hope this helps.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(MyInputModel myInputModel)
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = 1});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue and nothing was working for me. It turned out the controller I was redirecting to required Authorization - the [Authorize] attribute was preventing any redirection

```
   [Authorize]//comment this out
   public class HomeController : Controller {...}
```

Because I forgot to add app.UseAuthentication() to the code block in the Startup.cs.

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   ...
   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   ...
```

After adding the redirect began to work