# RedirectToAction is returning HTML Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, I am trying to implement user authentication. Credentials are stored in SQL table.

I have a login page, when user enters credentials I am calling the JavaScript function shown here. Instead of redirecting to home page, it is returning html content of home page. May I know what I am doing wrong?

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
    $('#lblvalidationmsg').text("");
    var username = $('#txtuserId').val();
    var password = $('#txtpassword').val();
    if (username != "" && password != "") {

      var LoginInfo = {};
      LoginInfo.UserName = username;
      LoginInfo.Password = password;
      LoginInfo.RedirectURL = getParameterByName("redirecturl");

      $.ajax({
        url: '/Users/IsValidUser',
        method: 'POST',
       // url: '@Url.Action("IsValidUser", "Users")',
       // datatype: "html",
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(LoginInfo),
        success: function (data) {
          if (data == "True") {
            $('#lblvalidationmsg').text("Sucess");
          }
          else {
            $('#lblvalidationmsg').text("Invalid User Name or Password.");
          }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
          $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
          $('#divError').show('fade');
        }
      });
    }
});
```

My controller method.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IsValidUser(LoginInfo loginInfo)
{
  bool isvalid = false;
  try
  {
    userhelper = new UserHelper();
    isvalid = userhelper.IsValidUser(loginInfo.UserName, loginInfo.Password);
    if (isvalid)
    {
      System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInfo.UserName, false);
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginInfo.RedirectURL))
      {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {

  }
   return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure of that `loginInfo.RedirectURL` is not empty?

Comment: For the first time it will be empty. so that i am trying to redirect login page to home page.

Comment: Why is it empty for the first time? Because this method is calling from your ajax function and it should not be empty. Did you debug it?

Comment: yes debugged it. Code is hitting  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); My worry is it is returning html content. I want it to redirect to home page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225030/redirecttoaction-not-changing-url-or-navigating-to-index-view